# Merge common columns in two tables into a single set of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, union

I have a database that stores the invoice information of customers in the following fashion

**Customer** - Stores customer information

```
ID
Name
Address
Type --ITS/TP
```

**Invoice** - Stores invoice details for customers

```
ID
Month
CustomerID
Total Amount
```

**InvoiceItemITS** - Stores invoice item details for ITS customers

```
ID
InvoiceID
DescriptionID
Price 
Volume
Amount
Description –- Non generic descriptions manually entered
Pipeline
```

**InvocieItemTP** - Stores invoice item details for TP customers

```
ID
InvoiceID
DescriptionID
Price 
Volume
Amount
Transaction
Start date 
End date
```

**Description** - Stores generic invoice item descriptions

```
ID
Name
```

I need to display all the invoices items for all the customers (both types) for given month. The result should include all columns of the Customer and Invoice tables and common columns in the InvoiceItemTP  and InvoiceItemITS with the Description column being the manually entered description if it exists else the generic description  for Description table.  InvoiceItemITS and InvoiceItemTP  are mutually exclusive and had around half the columns in common. I need help in combing  the common columns in InvoiceItemITS and InvoiceItemTP  into a single set of columns and deciding the description for each row. How can I do this?

FYI: I can't add or alter columns in the tables or the database structure

Comment: I need to display all the invoices items...and...and... Do it for me..!!

Answer (score 1):

You `LEFT JOIN` both tables and then use `CASE` on `Type` to select from appropriate table. Here is sample for few columns, you can do it for all columns you need.

```
SELECT 
   c.ID
  ,c.Name
  ,c.Type
  ,i.Month
  ,i.[Total Amount]
  ,CASE WHEN c.Type = 'ITS' THEN its.Price ELSE tp.Price END AS Price --construct for common columns
  ,CASE c.Type WHEN 'ITS' THEN its.Volume
               WHEN 'TP' THEN tp.Volume
               ELSE NULL 
    END AS Volume -- or something like this
  ,CASE WHEN c.Type = 'ITS' THEN COALESCE(its.Description, dits.Name)
        ELSE dtp.Name
   END AS Description -- this for description
FROM Customer c 
LEFT JOIN Invoice in ON in.CustomerID = c.ID
LEFT JOIN InvoiceItemITS its ON its.InvoiceID = in.ID
LEFT JOIN InvocieItemTP tp ON tp.InvoiceID = in.ID
LEFT JOIN [Description] dtp ON dtp .ID = tp.DescriptionID
LEFT JOIN [Description] dits ON dits.ID = its.DescriptionID
```